# How to I disconnect VisualSVN from my Solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

So I just downloaded TortoiseSVN, VisualSVN and VisualSVN Server.  I created a new repository and through VS2010, added my solution to said repository.  I then realized that I had some naming issues with my repository so I deleted it using the VisualSVN Server Manager thinking that I could go back to VS2010 and somehow drop the solutions connection to SVN, but I cannot figure out any way to do this?  I essentially want to start from scratch with this solution/connecting to SVN but I cannot seem to find a way for it to offer me the initial "Add this Solution to SVN" option.  I don't know if this is a TortiseSVN issue or VisualSVN but any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8):

Close Visual Studio then remove the subversion info by deleting all .svn folders recursively below the project folder. They are hidden so you will need to enable viewing of hidden files and folders. Open Visual Studio and VisualSVN should offer to add the solution to subversion again.